# How to create a List type field in schema using core service?

Tags: core-service, schema, keyword

I want to create a schema with a list field by using core service so I can select the keyword when I create a component. for this I create a "SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData" type field but I did not find any method in SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData class for the property of Values will be Selected from a List .

how I do this so I can select the category from the list and classify the component

Comment: I'm wondering, are you only using Visual Studio intellisense to see what is available? If so I can recommend downloading the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 Core Service API reference guide (.chm file) from the documentation. That gives a much better overview of what members are available for a given class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `singleLineTextFieldDefinitionData.List` to have list type field

```
SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData singleLineTextFieldDefinitionData = new SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData();
singleLineTextFieldDefinitionData.Name = "OptionField";
singleLineTextFieldDefinitionData.Description = "Option Field";
singleLineTextFieldDefinitionData.List = new SingleLineTextListDefinitionData()
{
    Entries = new String[] { "Yes", "No" }
};
```

Especially to target keyword related schema field with list type,

```
KeywordFieldDefinitionData keywordFieldDefinitionData = new KeywordFieldDefinitionData()
{
    Name = "MyList",
    Description = "It's My List",
    Category = new LinkToCategoryData()
    {
        IdRef = "Category-TCM-ID"
    },
    List = new ListDefinitionData()
    {
        Type = ListType.Tree
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks one more things I want to ask that in tridion gui when we checked the Values will be Selected from a List: property a category check box appear automatically and when we select the category checkbox our category are display in list how I do this using core service after list type field create

Comment: @pankajSharma: Updated with more detailed example related to keyword.

Comment: Check the schema source after you do it in the UI - this should give you enough pointers to "reverse-engineer" it. At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Yeah that's a great point.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData.List` property

Answer (score 1):

For a text based option list you can use the `SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData.List` property as explained in the given answers by @user978511 and @Siva.

If you want to populate the values in the list with Keywords from a Category, you will have to use the `KeywordFieldDefinitionData` class instead for your field. While in the SDL Tridion UI, it is initially shown as a Text field, this is underwater a Keyword field once you select a Category for the list.

The `KeywordFieldDefinitionData.Category` property is where you will be able to set the Category from which you need the Keywords. The `KeywordFieldDefinitionData.List` property should be automatically populated from that point onwards.